# Jquery Mobile App Link to Google Map Covers App

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile App.  In the App I have an anchor tag:

```html
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=street,state,city,zip" data-ajax="false" class="maps ui-link">link</a>
```

When the link is clicked from a browser, the link opens in a new window, but when the link is clicked from inside the app the google maps opens up in a window that covers the app and i'm not able to go back to the app.

I tried calling:

```js
$('.maps').click(function() {
window.open(this.getAttribute("href"), '_blank');
  return false
});
```

but it still behaves the same.

Is this a limitation of jquery mobile?  If I'm able to open the url in safari that will fix the issue.

Comment: are you using phonegap?

Comment: No, i'm just using Jquery Mobile with PHP.